# Windows Mobile 6 UI update problem

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-mobile

I have a windows mobile application written in C# that has more dialogs. I want to update a dialog, when an event is triggered. Here is the code:

```
 public void ServerStateChanged()
        {
            // update the interface
            try
            {
                if (this.Focused)
                {
                    this.noConnectionsLL.Text = this.tcpServer.ClientsCount.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
            }
        }
```

The code works a few times, but then I get this  `System.NotSupportedException` with this stacktrace: `at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr()\r\nat System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Focused()\r\nat DialTester.Communication.TCPServerView.ServerStateChanged()\r\nat ...`

Does it matter from which thread is triggered the event? because I can't figure out what the problem is, why it works a few times and then it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely to be a cross-thread issue.  Checking `this.InvokeRequired` at the top of the function and reacting accordingly would definitely improve the safety of the function.  Something like this:

```
public void ServerStateChanged()         
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new delegate
        {
            ServerStateChanged();
        }
        return;
    }

    if (this.Focused)                 
    {                     
        this.noConnectionsLL.Text = this.tcpServer.ClientsCount.ToString();
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or the lamba way as below.  And before I get criticised for using Control.BeginInvoke, BeginInvoke is threadsafe and is completely asynchronous (the call will put the update on the UI event queue).

```
    public void ServerStateChanged()  
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            if (this.Focused)
            {
                this.noConnectionsLL.Text = this.tcpServer.ClientsCount.ToString();
            }     
        }));
    }
```